# AutoMapper: Mapping class to viewmodels depending on the value of an enum

Tags: c#, .net, enums, automapper

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public MyEnum EnumValue {get;set;}
    public string PropA { get; set; }
}

public class Enum1ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string PropB {get; set;}
}

public class Enum2ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string PropC {get; set;}
}

public class Enum3ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string PropD {get; set;}
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public MyEnum EnumValue {get; set;}
    public string PropA {get;set;}
    public string PropB {get;set;}
    public string PropC {get;set;}
    public string PropD {get;set;}
    public string PropE {get;set;}
}

public class MapperProfile : Profile
{
    public MapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Enum1ViewModel, MyEntity>()
            .ForMember(m => m.EnumValue, o => o.UseValue(MyEnum.Value1)
            .ForMember(m => m.PropC, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.PropD, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.PropE, o => o.Ignore());

        CreateMap<Enum2ViewModel, MyEntity>()
            .ForMember(m => m.EnumValue, o => o.UseValue(MyEnum.Value2)
            .ForMember(m => m.PropB, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.PropD, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.PropE, o => o.Ignore());

        CreateMap<Enum3ViewModel, MyEntity>()
            .ForMember(m => m.EnumValue, o => o.UseValue(MyEnum.Value3)
            .ForMember(m => m.PropB, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.PropC, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.PropE, o => o.Ignore());

            // Question: How do I do the reverse mapping??
    }
}
```

I asked this question to Jimmy Bogard on twitter, but I thought that the answer could possibly help out more people then just myself.

If I get Jimmy's answer before he posts it here, or anyone of you guys I'll answer it myself.

Comment: What is the problem here in the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible, see https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/258. There was a pull request to address it, but it wouldn't work with ORMs like EF, which would cause more confusion than anything.

Your best bet is a `switch` statement on the enum and call `Mapper.Map` in your application code (which is probably more obvious anyway).

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up with in the end, a switch statement in an extension method. Thanks again for the swift help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try mapping your ViewModel directly to MyEntity and (depending on your configuration) AutoMapper may simply not map any properties that are not present in the former.

If that does not work for you, an option would be to use conditional mapping similar to this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyEntity , Enum1ViewModel>()
.ForMember(
    destination => destination.PropA ,
    option => 
    {
        option.Condition(rc => 
        {
            var myViewModel = (Enum1ViewModel)rc.InstanceCache.First().Value;
            return myViewModel.EnumValue == MyEnum.Value1;
        });

        option.MapFrom(source => source.PropA);
    }
);
```

More information here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Conditional-mapping

Answer (score 0):

since both classes use the enum this should be as simple as:

```
CreateMap<MyEntity, Enum1ViewModel>();
CreateMap<MyEntity, Enum2ViewModel>();
CreateMap<MyEntity, Enum3ViewModel>();
```